# Show Chrome extension version on options page?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've got my manifest file with my version number and an options page.  Is there a way to display the installed version and latest available version on the options page without needing to do it manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the current version of your extension using [`chrome.runtime.getManifest().version`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#method-getManifest).

In order to get the "latest version" of your extension, you need to download [`updates.xml`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/autoupdate.html#update_manifest), and extract the version number:

```
var extensionID = chrome.i18n.getMessage('@@extension_id');
var currentVersion = chrome.runtime.getManifest().version;
var url = 'https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx?x=id%3D' + extensionID + '%26v%3D' + currentVersion;

var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
x.open('GET', url);
x.onload = function() {
    var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(x.responseText, 'text/xml');
    // Get and show version info. Exercise for the reader.
};
x.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customize your request with PHP, avoiding to update the extension every time Google changes the API, I suggest the following

update_info.php (from your site):

```
<?php

    $last_ver;
    $googleupdate   = 'http://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx?response=updatecheck&x=id%3D__id__%26uc';
    $ver            = $_POST['ver'];
    $id             = $_POST['id'];

    //filter/control for post request very fast for this example
    if(isset($id) && isset($ver)){
        if(strlen($id)>0){
            $urlupdate = str_replace('__id__', $id, $googleupdate);
            $last_ver  = _GetLastVersion($urlupdate);
            if($last_ver>0 && $last_ver>$ver){
                echo 'New version available, v'.$last_ver;
            }else{
                echo 'Your version is update';
            }
        }else{
            echo 'Insert id for response';
        }
    }else{
        echo 'Insert data for response';
    }

    //if your server do not connect with file_get_contents() use this function
    function getContent ($url) {

            $ch = curl_init();

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);

            $output = curl_exec($ch);
            $info = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

            curl_close($ch);
            if ($output === false || $info != 200) {
              $output = null;
            }
            return $output;

    }

    //this function return 0 if error or not content load
    function _GetLastVersion($url){     
        try {
            $last=0;
            //if you have proble you can use getContent($url)
            $xmlcontent = file_get_contents($url);
            if($xmlcontent){
                $doc = new DOMDocument();
                $doc->loadXML($xmlcontent);
                $items = $doc->getElementsByTagName('updatecheck');
                foreach ($items as $item) {
                    if($item->getAttribute('version')>0){
                        return $item->getAttribute('version');
                    }
                }
                return $last;
            }else{
                return 0;
            }

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return 0;
        }       
    }
?>
```

in your extension send request to your webpage, now you are in control of your script, you can decide which answer back every time